# Run ODBC select statement from Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc, ssms

We have a linked server connecting to IBM iSeries server.  Usually, it is no problem using the linked server.  However, I came across a query that I can't run locally on Management studio because it is using IBM functions and grouping capabilities like:

Functions:

- Trim
- CVTDATE

Grouping in select statement (at field level), not in group by:

```
SELECT SUM(BOOKEDAMT('*CONACTIV', GLPDJC.GLDBK, GLPDJC.GLDPJ, GLPDJC.GLDEC1, GLPDJC.GLDRN1, GLPDJC.GLDJB, GLPDJC.GLDGL, GLPDJC.GLDCC, GLPDJC.GLDRN2, GLPDJC.GLDBT, GLPDJC.GLDBE, GLPDJC.GLDBL, 9, ((XCVTDATE(DATE (SUBSTRING({d '2017-06-30' }, 1, 10))))), GLPDJC.GLDEDT))
    ,field2
    ,field3
FROM .....
GROUP BY field2 field3
```

Question:  How do I run this query locally?  Is it possible?  I am not sure what the query is exactly doing in order to re-write it and make it run-able.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use OPENQUERY to pass the query along to the remote server.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql

Comment: I tried OPENQUERY and it didn't work because I was using linked server within my select statement.  No need for linked server clarification at each table when using OPENQuery :)